# Why map returns an iterator

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

The question is pretty clear, why does `map()` (as well as `zip()` and `filter()` but not `range()` which doesn't return an iterator) return an iterator? I mean I would expect it to return just an *iterable*, why this choice?

Comment: Why shouldn't it return an iterator?

Comment: Iterators _are_ iterable.

Comment: You are mixing up your terms, all your examples are iterable. `range()` is a *sequence*, while the others are not. Iterable means: you can call `iter()` on it and get an iterator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because returning an *iterable sequence* requires producing all new values *up front*.

That's not a good idea if the *input* is an iterator too, especially so if that iterator is *infinite*.

Mapping values through a callable, one by one, does not *require* all values to be processed in one go, so `map()` doesn't do that and instead applies the callable *on demand*. That way it can be used equally well on sequences and potentially infinite iterables.

If you want an iterable sequence as output, use a list comprehension instead:

```
[callable(elem) for elem in inputiterator]
```

Note that I used the term *iterable sequence* and not the more generic term *iterable*; *iterators* are *already* *iterable* too. An *iterable* object is any object that can *produce an iterator*, and an iterator is always its *own* iterator.

Comment: One question, according to "Because returning an iterable sequence requires producing all new values up front" `range(5)` doesn't return an iterator and it doesn't produce all values up front, it produces them on demand but it doesn't return an iterator

Comment: That's because range can *calculate* those values based on the index; it is a special case. `map()` *cannot* because it cannot count on the underlying iterable having indices.

Comment: If I write `m = map(my_func, [1, 2, 3])` couldn't `map()` calculate values based on the index?

Comment: It could, but that'd mean that it would have to change behaviour based on the input; instead it does one thing, and does that well. You can create your own `map()` implementation that is a sequence and does what you want quite easily. Implement `__len__` and `__getitem__`, where the latter does the function call when accessing indexes.